# Assignment vs Increment operation

Tags: c, performance, variable-assignment, increment

I am working on an application where I have to keep data sequenced, every unit of data comes with a sequence number where, I check if the sequence number is 1 greater than the previous one, if it is, I increase my received count by 1. My question is, Is there a difference between :
1. in increasing my received count by one.
AND
2. assigning the last received sequence number to received count.

Thanks.

Comment: `C#` \ `java` \ `javascript` \ `C` \ `Ruby` \ `Assembly` \...?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am working with C.

Comment: Certainly the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing, but I think I understand.  Incrementing the value with the `++` operator would be "faster" on the metal,  but by such a small amount it would be negligible unless your doing the operation a massive amount of times.

Comment: Thanks. My Application may get millions of units of data in a short time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like a classic premature optimization question to me. Generally increasing value would mean "fetch original->change->store", while assigning would be "fetch other->store new". The "other" would probably be fetched already, thus saving even more clock cycles. Thus assigning would probably be faster.

**BUT** increment by 1 is usually very well optimized by the compilers and CPU's so that it wouldn't require any fetching or storing. It can very well be done in one CPU command, thus eliminating any difference, and in fact making increment by 1 probably better option performance-wise.

Confused? Good.

Point is that this is the kind of optimization you should **not** be doing, unless you benchmarked a bottle neck. Then you benchmark the options and chose the best.

Comment: This answer might change if we start talking about a multi-threaded environment.  Specifically, it might be better to do a direct atomic store than a load/add/store which might not be bullet proof.

Comment: @keeda The other thing to do is test it... it'd probably take you less than five minutes to write a simple benchmark.

Comment: @littleadv, Which cpu does increment in one command and takes longer for assignment?